# Convert string data type date value into date format dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This is the given value to convert:

```
DECLARE @Dt VARCHAR(20) = '16-12-1997 00:00:00'
```

I want to convert into: `16-12-1997`

Attempt #1:

```
SELECT CAST(@Dt AS DATE)
```

Error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Attempt #2:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @Dt, 105)
```

Result:

```
16-12-1997 00:00:00
```

Attempt #3:

```
SELECT LEFT(@Dt, 10)
```

The attempt #3 works, but will it possible by convert/cast?

Comment: What is your objective here?  Do you want to convert a string to a date or datetime?  Do you want to _format_ a datetime _string_ in a certain way?  Something else?

Comment: Datetime string in the given way.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question.  Your starting datetime string can already give you the date string output you want via `LEFT`.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by:

```
DECLARE @Dt VARCHAR(20) = '16-12-1997 00:00:00'
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), @Dt);
```

Is this something what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The other way to do this is, it will error if the date is invalid and will allow only genuine date

```
DECLARE @Dt VARCHAR(20) = '16-12-1997 00:00:00'
SELECT format(CONVERT(DATE, @Dt,105),'dd-MM-yyyy');
```